# Ошибка laravel-echo-server при подключении к redis

Tags: php, linux, node.js, laravel, docker

Проект размещен в докер, есть отдельные контейнеры под редис и под ноду

```
node:
 image: node:12
 container_name: node
 volumes:
   - ./:/var/www
 working_dir: /var/www
 tty: true
 environment:
   - "REDIS_PORT=6379"
   - "REDIS_HOST=redis"
 links:
   - redis
 networks:
   - backend-network
   - frontend-network

redis:
 image: redis:6.0
 container_name: redis
 ports:
   - "63791:6379"
 networks:
   - backend-network
 restart: always
```

Захожу в контейнер node и пытаюсь запустить эхо-сервер `laravel-echo-server start` после чего я получаю следующий выхлоп:

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.6.2

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
```

Конект не удался, дальше происходит тоже самое, нода пытается запустить эхо-сервер, а к редису не достучаться. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ноде laravel

> environment:
>
> - "REDIS_PORT=6379"

и в ноде редиса

> ports:
>
> - "63791:6379"

Все ок с портами?
Ну и вопрос, почему оно стучится на 127.0.0.1. Я бы подебажил какие значения попадают в env в ноду с Laravel.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, по поводу ip все ок, он на локалке лежит. По портам пробовал как 6379 так и 63791

Comment: Проблема была в ip на который стучался node